# Derivative with respect to the normal vector and with respect to the radius

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose a function $f$ is defined on the boundary of a ball of radius $r$ in $ \mathbb{R}^{k} $ ($k\geq2$), and let $n_{i}$ be the inward normal vector. What is the relation between derivatives with respect to $n_{i}$ and with respect to $r$? Is it true to say that:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial n_{i}} =- \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}?$$

Comment: What sense does $\partial f /\partial r$ make in this context?

Comment: The same $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ that appears in the Green's formula: 
 $$\int_{D}(f\Delta g-g\Delta f)dx=\int_{\partial D}( g\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}-f\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial r} )d\sigma.$$

Comment: But you only said $f$ is defined on the boundary.

Comment: We may assume it is defined on a neighborhood of the closure of the ball. Can it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $D$ is the ball centered at the origin and of radius $r_0$. Then for every $x\in\partial D$ you have that the inward normal is given by $n_i=-x/r_0$ and so the normal derivative is given by
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial n_i}(x)=\nabla f(x)\cdot n_i=-\nabla f(x)\cdot \frac{x}{r_0}.$$
Now assume that $k=2$ for simplicity and consider the function $f$ in polar coordinates, that is
$$g(r,\theta):=f(r \cos\theta,r \sin\theta).$$
Then by the chain rule
\begin{align}\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}(r,\theta)&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(r \cos\theta,r \sin\theta)\cos\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(r \cos\theta,r \sin\theta)\sin\theta\\
&=\nabla f(r \cos\theta,r \sin\theta)\cdot\frac1r(r \cos\theta,r \sin\theta)\end{align}
and so at the point $x=(r_0 \cos\theta,r_0 \sin\theta)$ you do have
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}(r_0,\theta)=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial n_i}(r_0 \cos\theta,r_0 \sin\theta).$$
In higher dimension the proof is probably similar, just messier.